# Jquery не отдает текст элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть набор одинаковых тегов с разным содержимым.
Как видите при нажатии я вызываю функцию `helper_command()`.

```js
function helper_command() {
    alert($(this).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command()">
  Создать сет
</div>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command()">
  Мои сеты
</div>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command()">
  Баланс
</div>
```

Но когда я нажимаю у меня выводится пустой текст, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что контекст не передаётся. Чтобы его передать можно воспользоваться методами `.apply()` или `.call()`.

```js
function helper_command() {
    alert($(this).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command.apply(this)">
  Создать сет
</div>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command.apply(this)">
  Мои сеты
</div>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command.apply(this)">
  Баланс
</div>
```

Либо, что еще лучше, передавать объект события.

```js
function helper_command(event) {
    alert($(event.target).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command(event)">
  Создать сет
</div>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command(event)">
  Мои сеты
</div>
<div class="command" onclick="helper_command(event)">
  Баланс
</div>
```

Comment: а еще лучше не использовать инлайн-обработчики и написать `$(".command").click(...)`